# Does a pomegranate tree need propping up?

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, support, pomegranate

We planted a small pomegranate tree (about 1 foot tall) a couple of years ago. The tree has been growing nicely, now standing about 3-4 feet tall. Last year we had a bunch of flowers but no fruit. This spring I pruned it fairly aggressively and we now have a lot of new growth. The new branches seem to be bending under their own weight, some have now bent all the way down to the ground. I am wondering, is this normal or should I give the tree some support?

Answer (score 4):

possibly even more pruning for the first three years?

Purdue have some information on propagation, pruning, when to pick ,etc. But it does sound a lot of pruning early on to create a strong frame, and then irrigation when fruit start to form:

> Rooted cuttings or seedlings are set out in pre-fertilized pits 2 ft (60 cm) deep and wide and are spaced 12 to 18 ft (3.5-5.5 m) apart, depending on the fertility of the soil. Initially, the plants are cut back to 24 to 30 in (60-75 cm) in height and after they branch out the lower branches are pruned to provide a clear main stem. Inasmuch as fruits are borne only at the tips of new growth, it is recommended that, for the first 3 years, the branches be judiciously shortened annually to encourage the maximum number of new shoots on all sides, prevent straggly development, and achieve a strong, well-framed plant. After the 3rd year, only suckers and dead branches are removed.

http://www.hort.purdue.edu/newcrop/morton/pomegranate.html

Comment: that relates to pruning, but what about supporting the bent branches?

Comment: I was thinking they might be bending because more pruning is required?

Comment: @winmaed do you think its adviseable to prune now, in the middle of summer? I actually prined it down to pretty much close to just the the main stem in the winter.

Comment: I'm not an expert and only have a peach, but the books usually suggest spring for fruit trees. I pruned my peach at the end of its first summer in the ground and it didn't harm it. (wrong time for cuttings though - and they all failed)

Comment: Often they grow as low shrubs.